# How can we implement copy paste of diagram elements in bpmn.io editor?

Tags: bpmn.io

I am new to bpmn.io and I need to implement copy (of a part of workflow diagram) and paste (it in the same or another bpmn io editor) in bpmb-io editor. How this can be achieved?